# urllib2 works where request doesn't

Tags: python, urllib2, python-requests

EDIT: Solved! See below.

I'm a recent convert to using the `requests` library for python. However, I'm encountering a situation where `urllib2` works and `requests` doesn't.

```
import requests, urllib2
url = "http://thepiratebay.se/search/test/0/7/0"
print urllib2.urlopen(url).getcode() # 200 - OK!
print requests.get(url).status_code # 400 :(
```

I've also tried setting headers but it doesn't seem to fix the problem, so I've included my minimal example. Other thoughts: is `urllib2` somehow handling the redirect to thepiratebay.sx correctly while `requests` doesn't?

Thanks in advance!

---

Thanks for the help all, I upgraded `requests` (1.0.4 => 1.2.2) and it solved the problem. Oops, should have considered that earlier!

Comment: I tested it with the same url, and got `200` in return.

Comment: print urllib2.urlopen(url).get_code() should be print urllib2.urlopen(url).getcode()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requests library does handle redirects by default, as seen [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history).

In fact, I cannot reproduce your issue:
[image]

Perhaps try it again?

Comment: Thanks for trying it out on your side, I figured out I needed to upgrade requests when I saw your python version and thought "hmm". I've updated my question and have accepted your answer since it put me on the right path!

Answer (score 0):

Both of these should handle redirects by default

From http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html, urllib2 handles "basic and digest authentication, redirections, cookies and more."

From http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#redirection-and-history "Requests will automatically perform location redirection while using the GET and OPTIONS verbs."

Both of these return a 200 response for me.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I appreciate your speedy responses.